# Hotel Booking system architecture for room available efficiency

Tags: sql-server, database, architecture

As I'm trying to develop a Hotel Booking System, I'm curious which approach is best for the system architecture. For now, I having Hotel Room details, Customer details, and Booking details when a customer book a hotel room on certain date.

> Room available = Total Room - Room Reserved

Now I'm using a query to retrieve room available on that date given based on the room reserved taken on the particular date that customer chosen . For example, customer book a room from `3 August 2016` till `6 August 2016`. Then I will retrieve the date in between 3 August - 6 August from booking details. I will loop each day into this SQL statement.

```
Select * from bookingDetails where theDate between StartDate and EndDate and RoomType = 'Something'
```

Then I will take the date set to sum up the Room reserved and get the Total room.
This statement will be triggered when customer selecting the Date

Or I should create one more table as Available Room and store 5 years calendar with the total Room. It will deduce when customer made a room booking.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need any other tables.
You just have to look for all booked rooms and exclude them:

```
Select * 
from tbl_Rooms
WHERE RoomType = 'Something' and 
    Room_ID not in (
        Select Room_ID 
        from bookingDetails 
        where theDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
    );
```

However, that query returns rooms, which are available ONLY for the whole period. Here is the query to show all available rooms by days (within 255 days range):

```
;WITH Pass0 as (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1)) as A(C)),
  Pass1 as (select 1 as C from Pass0 as A, Pass0 as B),--16 rows
  Pass2 as (select 1 as C from Pass1 as A, Pass1 as B),--256 rows  
  Dates as (SELECT DATEADD(d,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1,@StartDate) as AvailDate FROM Pass2)
SELECT d.AvailDate, r.* FROM tbl_Rooms as r
INNER JOIN Dates as d ON AvailDate < @EndDate
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bookingDetails as b WHERE b.theDate = d.AvailDate and b.Room_ID = r.Room_ID)
ORDER BY r.Room_Number, d.AvailDate;
```

Comment: Instead of in detail of each room, what i have is general hotel room information for the table . For example total Room, Types, Price and general description for the hotel room details. Therefore, i cant use Room_ID to filter it out.

Comment: So, that is probably an answer for your question. You need at least three tables: tbl_Rooms(ID, Number, Type, Floor, Etc); tbl_Bookings(Room_ID,Client_ID, Date); tbl_Clients(ID,Name,Etc); If you try to use date range in the tbl_Bookings table then you have to re-write my second query.